# how to pass variables between functions Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a function like this in views.py:

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.POST['username']
        pwd = request.POST['password'] 
        #and other code
```

And then i have another function like this:

```
def reservations(request):
    try:
        c = Utilisateur.objects.get(username = uname)
        reserve = Reserve.objects.get(client = c)
        return render (request, 'reservation.html', {'reserve':reserve})
    except:
        return HttpResponse ('you have no reservations!')
```

And i want to use the "uname" variable of the first function but it doesn't work any solution?

Comment: cant you use a sessions to store values    session = sessions.Session()

Comment: idk how to do that can you help me

Comment: If you're signing in the user in your signin view, then you don't need to pass uname.  Assuming you're using the built in django authentication, you can access the User object as `request.user` any time after they are logged in.  Django sets a cookie so it knows who the user is.

Comment: thats the problem im not using the built in django authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first view, save the value in the session:

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.POST['username']
        request.session['uname'] = uname
```

Then in the second view, fetch the value from the session:

```
def reservations(request):
    try:
        uname = request.session['uname']
        c = Utilisateur.objects.get(username = uname)
```